# How to make iPhone web app links from opening in Safari?

Tags: html, ios, iphone, uiwebview, mobile-safari

I have a html page on my webserver and we make it as a qrcode scanning in another app (QRcode scanner) on my iphone.

When we scanned it, it opens on the App's UIWebview, there is a link in the html page, and we want to make the link opened by iPhone Safari directly, not this UIWebview.

Html code:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="./jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <a href="http://host/js/another-html-page.html">hello</a>

    <script>
        $( document ).on ("click", "a", function( event ) {
            event.preventDefault();
            location.href = $( event.target ).attr ( "href" );
        });
        </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

If the QR code scanner is your app, then it's as simple as

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com"]]
```

Otherwise if you're saying that the QR code scanner app is downloaded from the app store and you have no control over its source code, there's nothing you can do on your web page that can force it.

Comment: Thanks for Allen's replay. Because we have an enterprise app and we put it on the webserver, as you know, from ios7, we need to use https protocol to open the html page, so that we can download our app. Unfortunately, we have only self signed certification, so user need to download and install the cer firstly and then they can download and install our app.  And we provided a qrcode for user to access our web page, but here is the problem, in the webview, user can not install the cer through click the download link, how we can to handle this issue. Any suggestion ? Great thanks.

Comment: But it's fine to open the link in the iphone safari directly, we can download the certification and install it firstly, then click the link to install our app.

Comment: Are you asking how you can launch Safari from within your QR code scanner app?